# Merge 3 bands (r,g,b) images with phase shift to 1 rgb image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, gis, qgis

I have a customized camera, which contains 3 individual lens+filters arranged in a triangle so in every shot I get 3 single band grayscale images (r, g, b). I want to merge them to get an RGB.

The problem is, since the 3 lens are physically separated, the image captured by them are not aligned. As a result, when I use command qdal_merge in the software pack QGIS, the result looks weird. I may also need to adjust the weight of the r,g,b. I put the raw r,g,b images and the output I generated using qgis in this [dropbox folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k8qxigrkyxlrfxq/AADANRMc533KTsazU5BSm83Ea?dl=0).

Is there existing open-source tool to do the alignment and merge? If not, how can I do it using opencv?

Comment: Can you post the three grayscale images? Do you know in advance the mutual displacement?

Comment: You might have better luck on http://gis.stackexchange.com/ for questions on how to use GIS.

Comment: @Miki I updated the question with link to the raw images.

Comment: @mkirk For me this is more like an image processing problem than a gis problem. I'm using qgis just because a friend of mine is familiar with it and suggest me to use it.

Comment: you could try things like keypoint matching, optical flow etc. or stereo camera matching, but since your images are made from different scenes (different colors) many approaches might not work there. Can you stereo-calbrate your whole camera system with an appropriate calibration pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Combining R,G,B images is possible using a simple pixel intensity distance metric like Sum of Squared Distances (SSD). A better metric is the Normalized Cross-Correlation (NCC) (see Wikipedia) which first normalizes an image matrix into a unit vector, and computes the dot product of such unit vectors (from 2 input images). The higher the NCC value, the greater the similarity of the two input images.
However, NCC similarity may be insufficient for computing the best alignment of two high resolution images, such as the TIFF images you provide. One should therefore use a downsampling method as described below
to align two input images at a smaller size and then simply compute the offset as you rescale the images.

So for the input images, `red`, `green` and `blue`, there are two approaches to align them into a single RGB image:

1. Consider the `blue` image as the reference image for example, w.r.t. which we align the `red` and `green` images. Now consider `red` and `blue` images. Within a certain window, compute the best alignment offset of the `red` and `blue` images using the NCC similarity metric, and find the `shifted_red` image. Do the same for the `green` and `blue` images. Now combine the `shifted_red`, `shifted_green` and `blue` images to get the final RGB image.
2. For high-resolution images, decide a `scale_count`. Recursively, at each step resize the image by half, compute the offset of the `red` image w.r.t. the `blue` image, rescale the offset and apply it. The benefit of doing such a recursive multi-scale alignment is decrease in computation time and increase in accuracy of alignment (you don't know the best window size for searching for alignment offsets for solution (1), so this will work better). Repeat this approach for computing the alignment for `green` and `blue` channels, and then combine the final results as in (1).

Since this problem is common in assignments of computational photography courses, I am not going to share any code. I have, however implemented the two approaches and experimented with the images you provide. I don't know which of the input images is red, so I have two results (rescaled to decrease file size):

If `IMG_0290_1.tif` is Red, `IMG_0290_2.tif` is Green and `IMG_0290_3.tif` is blue:

[RGB result if `red`:1, `green`:2, `blue`:3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gvz8h.png)

If `IMG_0290_3.tif` is Red, `IMG_0290_2.tif` is Green and `IMG_0290_1.tif` is blue (this looks more correct to me):

[RGB result if `red`:3, `green`:2, `blue`:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edtxN.png)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the detailed answer! In my data 3 is red, and your result looks great!  I wonder what's the efficiency of your code, since I have about 1000 set of r,g,b images. Could you run your code over the single data set I have for 1000 times and let me know the run time?   Regarding the implementation, I'm not doing a coding assignment, so it'll be really nice if you could share the code. Otherwise, could you let me know what language and libraries (opencv? I have to learn from beginning) did you use to write your code?  Thanks!!